# Operator Precedence Puzzle

Tags: c++

I have variables with their initial value defined as: `x = 10, y = 4, z = 1` and what's those variable values in `y>>=x&0x2&&z`  ?

I would do:

```
y >>= ((Fun1) && z)
```

`Fun1 = x&0x2`, that is the bit operation of `1010 & 0010 = 0010`, or 2 in decimal;

`Fun1 && z` returns 1, or 0001 in binary

Then my question is what is the operation of

```
y >>= 0001
```

gives me?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x = 10, y = 4, z = 1;

    y >>= x&0x2&&z;

    cout << "x: " << x << endl;
    cout << "y: " << y << endl;
    cout << "z: " << z << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Should this get a homework tag?

Comment: What is the difference between `&` and `&&`? What are the operator's precedence?

Comment: It is a puzzle which I found online and I knew how to compile it and I dinn't want just take the results that computer give to me for granted. Therefore I hope someone can tell me what the computer does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
y >>= 1
```

is the same as

```
 y = y >> 1
```

So it should effectively integer-divide y by 2.

Comment: Cool. There is a >>= operator called Bitwise shift right assignment, right? You seems used the shorthand as in foo += 1 => foo = 1 + foo, am I right?

Comment: Right. Was your question what that operator was? I was answering: "what is the operation of y >>= 0001 gives me?"

Answer (score 6):

1. When in doubt use braces
2. When in doubt use braces
3. When in doubt use braces